# Ubuntu 16.04 BCM4313/BCM2070 Bluetooth Firmware Issues

Tags: drivers, bluetooth, broadcom, firmware, disconnect

This is an issue I encountered with Ubuntu 14.04 as well.

Sometimes the bluetooth works perfectly. But other times, normally on a fresh boot, bluetooth is disabled and cannot be enabled. After rebooting 2-3 times, bluetooth starts.

I tried similar other solutions to the problem on other Broadcom chips, but they do not work for me, as I cannot find the particular firmware for my chip.

```
$ lsusb
Bus 002 Device 003: ID 04f2:b293 Chicony Electronics Co., Ltd 
Bus 002 Device 002: ID 8087:0020 Intel Corp. Integrated Rate Matching Hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 0a5c:21b4 Broadcom Corp. BCM2070 Bluetooth 2.1 + EDR
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 8087:0020 Intel Corp. Integrated Rate Matching Hub
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub

$ dmesg | grep Blue
[    3.840242] usb 1-1.3: Product: Broadcom 2070 Bluetooth
[    9.067121] Bluetooth: Core ver 2.21
[    9.067151] Bluetooth: HCI device and connection manager initialized
[    9.067157] Bluetooth: HCI socket layer initialized
[    9.067162] Bluetooth: L2CAP socket layer initialized
[    9.067171] Bluetooth: SCO socket layer initialized
[   11.218643] Bluetooth: hci0 command 0x1009 tx timeout
[   11.300740] Bluetooth: BNEP (Ethernet Emulation) ver 1.3
[   11.300746] Bluetooth: BNEP filters: protocol multicast
[   11.300754] Bluetooth: BNEP socket layer initialized

$ dmesg | grep Broad
[    3.840242] usb 1-1.3: Product: Broadcom 2070 Bluetooth
[    3.840246] usb 1-1.3: Manufacturer: Broadcom Corp
[    7.636612] wlan0: Broadcom BCM4727 802.11 Hybrid Wireless Controller 6.30.223.248 (r487574)
```

This issue has been a pain in the ass. Please help.

Thank you.

[Bluetooth Settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q8xI8.png)

Edit:

```
$ rfkill list
0: phy0: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
1: brcmwl-0: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
6: hci0: Bluetooth
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no


$ dpkg -l *bcm*
Desired=Unknown/Install/Remove/Purge/Hold
| Status=Not/Inst/Conf-files/Unpacked/halF-conf/Half-inst/trig-aWait/Trig-pend
|/ Err?=(none)/Reinst-required (Status,Err: uppercase=bad)
||/ Name           Version      Architecture Description
+++-==============-============-============-=================================
ii  bcmwl-kernel-s 6.30.223.248 amd64        Broadcom 802.11 Linux STA wireles
un  bcmwl-modalias <none>       <none>       (no description available)
rc  libcmis-0.4-4  0.4.1-3ubunt amd64        CMIS protocol client library
un  libcmis-0.5-5  <none>       <none>       (no description available)
ii  libcmis-0.5-5v 0.5.1-2ubunt amd64        CMIS protocol client library


$ sudo lshw -C network
*-network               
   description: Wireless interface
   product: BCM4313 802.11bgn Wireless Network Adapter
   vendor: Broadcom Corporation
   physical id: 0
   bus info: pci@0000:02:00.0
   logical name: wlan0
   version: 01
   serial: e0:2a:82:a7:1a:84
   width: 64 bits
   clock: 33MHz
   capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list ethernet physical wireless
   configuration: broadcast=yes driver=wl0 driverversion=6.30.223.248 (r487574) ip=192.168.1.2 latency=0 multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11abg
   resources: irq:16 memory:c5400000-c5403fff
*-network
   description: Ethernet interface
   product: RTL8101/2/6E PCI Express Fast/Gigabit Ethernet controller
   vendor: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
   physical id: 0
   bus info: pci@0000:03:00.0
   logical name: eth0
   version: 05
   serial: 98:4b:e1:bf:35:8b
   size: 10Mbit/s
   capacity: 100Mbit/s
   width: 64 bits
   clock: 33MHz
   capabilities: pm msi pciexpress msix vpd bus_master cap_list ethernet physical tp mii 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd autonegotiation
   configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=r8169 driverversion=2.3LK-NAPI duplex=half firmware=rtl_nic/rtl8105e-1.fw latency=0 link=no multicast=yes port=MII speed=10Mbit/s
   resources: irq:26 ioport:3000(size=256) memory:c1404000-c1404fff memory:c1400000-c1403fff
```

Comment: Do you have broadcom-sta-dkms installed? In terminal, type `dpkg -l *broadcom*` and report back.

Comment: No packages found matching broadcom.

Comment: @heynnema thanks for the reply. I found that the firmware was not loaded properly. Running:
    sudo modprobe -r btusb
    sudo modprobe btusb

seems to load the firmware.

Comment: So I added the codes in /etc/rc.local.

Seems to work fine now.

However, I would like to know what you suggest other than my workaround.

Comment: Does your wireless work? I need to know if I need to recommend installing broadcom software. As a temporary workaround, I'd remove the commands you put into rc.local, and add `btusb` to `/etc/modules`. Last question... your subject title indicates BCM4313... where did you get that number from? In your dmesg I see a BCM4727.

Comment: @heynnema yes, wifi worked flawlessly previously as well, it was just the bluetooth that didn't load up.

Comment: @heynnema lspci shows the wireless controller as BCM4313.

Comment: adding `btusb` to `/etc/modules` does not help. 
`lsusb`shows the wireless controller as BCM4313.

Comment: btusb is a kernel module, and adding it to /etc/moduless assures that it's loaded at boot time. What did you see when you added it? Did you remove your rc.local workaround? Two questions... show me the output of `dkms status` and, make a wireless connection, then pull down `Connection Information` from the network panel icon, and tell me what driver it shows for the wireless.

Comment: ps: and the output of `rfkill list`

Comment: ps: and the output of `dpkg -l *bcm*` and `sudo lshw -C network`

Comment: Please file a bug report against package linux [here](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/ReportingBugs)  It sounds like btusb may be trying to query the bluetooth too early or btbcm might be trying to upload the firmware too early causing this issue.  Include the info on your work around of removing btusb and reloading it.  I would also try removing btusb from /etc/modules and blacklisting it, then use etc/rc.local to `modprobe btusb` after a command `sleep 30` and see if that works for you

Comment: Are you booting off of a SSD? And, are you dual-booting with Windows?

Comment: @heynnema I don't think this issue is related to boot. I just found out that waking up my laptop from suspend causes the same issue. 
I have to use the modprobe commands to make bluetooth work again on wake up.

Other than that, ubuntu is the sole OS running off an SSD.

Comment: @heynnema yes, I removed the rc.local workaround when adding `btusb` to `/etc/modules`

Comment: I hadn't noticed that you edited in some of the command output that I had requested earlier. Thanks. I do have recommendations about both drivers that I see. Few more questions. Do you use wireless, or hardwire ethernet cable. Do you manually have to rebuild your current wireless driver after every kernel upgrade, or are you using dkms? Give me the output of `dkms status`. Do you have Intel processors? Check the output of `dpkg -l *microcode*`. How much RAM and how much swap on the SSD? Sorry for all of the detailed questions, but I want to make the best suggestion that I can for you.